# Sendmail relaying mails results in invalid sender address

Tags: centos, sendmail, centos7

So i finally got the sendmail-google relay working, but now the sender address is causing troubles. For example: if in php i set: `$headers = "From: Someone <someone@something.com>";` the sender name someone will be correct, but since i am relaying through google the sender address will be mygoogleusername@gmail.com. I've tried setting a fixed sender address in sendmail config, but that didn't help.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think gmail allows that.

A nice explaination below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460240/spoof-from-address-through-gmail

I am not sure what exactly your requirements are, but what about using free 3rd party SMTP services Sendgrid, SparkPost, Mandrill etc in sendmail relay config?

which allows you to do so.